# Integrate clock widget in my application

Tags: android, android-widget

Is there a way thru which I can integrate (or reuse) the Android built in widgets (like clock or battery) in my application?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so you can use another app (widget is actually another app) inside your app, but if you need a clock to put into your app you can use `AnalogClock` view.

//
as I saw a code of widget, it consist of `RemoteViews` and the constructor of it needs `package name`, and the `layout id`